# How to fix 'ImportError: No module named pssevrsn'

Tags: python, psse

Try to use python to call psse. but something wrong with importing dyntools.

```py
from __future__ import division

import os, sys, math, csv, time
PSSPY_location = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\PTI\PSSE34\PSSPY27'
PSSE_location = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\PTI\PSSE34\PSSBIN'
sys.path.append(PSSPY_location)
os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + PSSPY_location
os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + PSSE_location

import socket
import struct
import numpy, copy

import initialize_mute as mt    # mute all psse outputs
# import psse34
import dyntools
import psspy
import redirect
```

```
import dyntools
  File ".\dyntools.py", line 51, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pssevrsn
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: The code should return a syntax error because of the braces. Did you check to see if you have the package `pssevrsn` in your `site-packages`? If you are using a relative import, are you sure that `pssevrsn` is in the right place?

Comment: Which version of python are you using? 2 or 3?

Comment: Why `import psse34` is commented in your code?

Comment: Did you try `pip install dyntools`?

Comment: this package pssevrsn is a .py document under PSSBIN.

Comment: I use python2, because psse only supports python2

Comment: dyntools seems to be a part of psse taht cant be pip installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PSSE manual indicates you need to define `PSSPY_location` and `PSSE_location` in your script but here is another option to tell Python where your PSSE installation is.

Create a file with extension `.pth`, (e.g., `__psspy__.pth`) in the `site-packages` directory of your Python installation.  This could likely be `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\__psspy.pth__` for you.  The *contents* of this file will simply be `C:\Program Files (x86)\PTI\PSSE34\PSSPY27`.  Whenever you startup your python interpreter it will looks for paths contained in `.pth` files in this directory and will look for python modules in these locations when you make `import` statements.

Then your script should be the following:

```
import psse34
import psspy
import dyntools
import redirect
```

If you still can't import `dyntools` then make sure it is where it should be, i.e., `C:\Program Files (x86)\PTI\PSSE34\PSSPY27\dyntools.pyc`

For PSSE v34 remember to always do `import psse34` before importing any other PSSE related python modules.

Answer (score 0):

I made a copy of pssevrsn from Bin directory to the Python27 directory and it didn't made errors for me.
I hope it works for